# What is the pythonic way of instantiating a class, calling one of its methods, and returning it from a lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda

I am dealing with widgets and signals and I want to bind a signal to a certain callback. Since I don't really need to create a named callback function in the case of interest, I am defining it as a lambda function. However, the way it integrates with other classes is best described by the following minimal working example:

```
class Foo():
    def parse(self, what):
        self.bar = what

foo = lambda x = Foo(): (x.parse("All set"), x)[-1]

print(foo().bar)
'All set'
```

The lambda function needs to instantiate a class, call one of its members to parse a string and change its internal state, and return the instantiated class. The only way to do this that I can think of at the moment is as shown in the above example: pass the instance as the default argument, create a list where the first element is the call to the method and the second is the instance itself, then select the last element.

Is there a more pythonic and elegant way of obtaining the same result?

EDIT: A few caveats: In the actual code the class Foo is defined in other modules, and I'm passing the lambda as an argument to another function, hence why I don't really need to name the callback. Indeed, what I actually have is something that looks like

```
widget.bind( 'some_signal', lambda t, x = Foo(): (x.parse(t), x)[-1] )
```

Comment: You can add def __init__(self,param):

Comment: Why not make it a alternate constructor using a class method? Or a default value in `__init__`? In general, all attributes should exist by the end of `__init__`, even if they're just `None`.

Comment: the class Foo is not defined by me in the actual code. As I can in principle create another child class, I prefer not to do it

Comment: and then call it f = Foo(param=your_param)

Answer (score 9):

The most pythonic solution is to not use a lambda:

```
def foo():
    x = Foo()
    x.parse("All set")
    return x

print(foo().bar)
```

Lambdas in python are a syntactic convenience and are strictly less powerful than named functions.

Comment: And OP seems to have turned it into a named function anyways by equating it to `foo` so this literally does the exact same thing.

Comment: in the actual code, the lambda is passed as an argument to a function

Comment: @Phoenix87 so what? You can pass a regular function too, they're first class objects in Python. This is much easier to read than a `lambda`, and e.g. `widget.bind('some_signal', foo_factory)` is clear.

Comment: So is the main problem code readability then? Because for the problem at hand, I don't really care that lambdas are less powerful that named functions, seems it does the job anyway.

Comment: @Phoenix87 no, the problem is that you can't assign value to variables in lambda's

Answer (score 2):

A factory function achieves the goal of avoiding a separate named function in the code that wires the callback. I would consider this pythonic. Using a lambda function that does what you have to do ist definitely not pythonic.

```
def create_callback(data):
    def callback():
        x = Foo()
        x.parse(data)
        return x
    return callback
```

Comment: I can see how to write alternative code that avoids using lambdas. My question is about the pythonic way of achieving the goal.

Comment: I edited the answer slightly. Avoiding the lambda is pythonic in this case. You could also write a wrapper class with a __call__() method to serve as a callback, but that does make the code not look "nicer".

Answer (score 0):

based on @Vaibhav Sagar answer, a bit modified:

```
class Foo():
    def parse(self, what):
        self.bar = what


def foo_factory(what):
    instance = Foo()
    instance.parse(what)
    return instance


all_set = foo_factory('All set')
ok = foo_factory('Ok')
ready = foo_factory('ready')

print(all_set)
print(all_set.bar)
print(ok)
print(ok.bar)
print(ready)
print(ready.bar)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f56a176cc50>
All set
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f56a176cc88>
Ok
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f56a176ccf8>
ready
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
def callback():
    x = Foo()
    x.parse("All set")
    return x

widget.bind('some_signal', callback)
```

---

**Note** that your lambda will instanciate `Foo()` only the first time the code is interpreted.

Indeed,

```
foo = lambda d=dict(): d

d = foo()
d['hello'] = 'world'
print(foo()) # This will print {'hello': 'world'} instead of {}
```

Comment: I can see how to write alternative code if I was the one defining the class Foo, but this is provided by other modules and I'd prefer not to change it.

Comment: @Phoenix87, ok I didn't know. I edited my answer. As some user previously pointed out, it's ok to avoid lambdas -- also, who said that lambdas are pythonic?